# How is it possible, python, argsort?

Tags: python, numpy

I dont understand how is it possible ? Where is the bug ?

```
print vals
==>[ 0.0211958  0.0241981  0.0309122  0.0212591  0.0209115  0.405682  0.0248237  0.0213012  0.0211533  0.0211239]
print ny.sort(vals)
==>[ 0.0209115  0.0211239  0.0211533  0.0211958  0.0212591  0.0213012  0.0241981  0.0248237  0.0309122  0.405682 ]
print ny.argsort(vals)
==>[4 9 8 0 3 7 1 6 2 5]
```

The order must not be not [4 9 8 0 3 7 1 6 2 5]

thanks,

Comment: Where is the bug? I don't see any.

Answer (score 2):

`argsort()` returns the indices that would sort the array. In your example, it appears to do just that:

- 0.0209115 appears at offset 4 in the original array
- 0.0211239 appears at offset 9
- 0.0211533 appears at offset 8
- and so on

Answer (score 1):

Why do you believe it's a bug? It really prints the indices of the fields in the order you would need to place them in order to sort the array.